# Why doesn't numpy flatten() work after converting a nested list into an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, flatten

I created a nested list and converted both the inner lists and the whole list into a numpy array, but numpy flatten() failed to flatten the final array.

```
a = [1]
b = [2, 3]
c = [4, 5, 6]
d = [7, 8]
e = [9]
lst = [a, b, c, d, e]
arr = np.array([np.array(l) for l in lst], dtype='object')
print(type(arr))
print(arr.flatten())
```

I got the following output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[array([1]) array([2, 3]) array([4, 5, 6]) array([7, 8]) array([9])]
```

expected output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: `flatten` is like `reshape`.  It does not work across that object dtype boundary.  Use `np.hstack` to concatenate the list of arrays.

Comment: `sum(lst, [])` should do the trick

Comment: @onyambu, `sum` only works if the elements are lists.

Comment: You can try `functools.reduce(operator.iconcat, lst, [])`.

Answer (score 0):

You got ndarray of ndarrays, which is not 2d array.

Also, ndarray should have same size for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should flatten it properly, and then make a nd array. Like this:

```
arr = np.array([j for i in lst for j in i], dtype='object')
```